# Error installing poppler with homebrew with Mac Ventura 13

Tags: homebrew, poppler, macos-ventura

I am trying to install poppler with homebrew which is dependency used by many packages but it gives me this error:

```
$ brew install poppler
==> Fetching poppler
Warning: Building poppler from source as the bottle needs:
- HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar (yours is /Users/user/Applications/homebrew/Cellar)
- HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local (yours is /Users/user/Applications/homebrew)
==> Downloading https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-data-0.4.11.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/d0ce5fea7a038ced91deafbd2d9d78074b6123ce1571c4ff59e3c4f2c9142e0f--poppler-data-0.4.11.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-23.02.0.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/ada65f4ad8ce97f96509088f1b1951148699a9b6cf54d9cbaafd3a0442d8436b--poppler-23.02.0.tar.xz
==> cmake -S . -B build_shared -DBUILD_GTK_TESTS=OFF -DENABLE_BOOST=OFF -DENABLE_CMS=lcms2 -DENABLE_GLIB=ON -DENABLE_QT5=OFF -DENABLE_QT6=OFF -DENABLE_UNSTABLE_API_ABI_HEADERS=ON -DWITH_GObjectIntrospection=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=@loader_path/../lib
Last 15 lines from /Users/user/Library/Logs/Homebrew/poppler/01.cmake:
  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.



-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    BUILD_TESTING


CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core!
```

I opened a ticket at the poppler site:

- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/1335

But they closed it, so I am looking for further help

I have tried cleaning homebrew, uninstall/reinstall but the error still persists

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This started occurring when you upgraded to MacOS Ventura. OS upgrades do not automatically install the Xcode developer tools for your version of MacOS, so `Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/*` doesn't exist.

*The `BUILD_TESTING` bit is a warning, not an error.*

The actual error message will be contained in the Homebrew build log, which based on your question is located at `/Users/user/Library/Logs/Homebrew/poppler/01.cmake`.

Despite the snippet displayed by Homebrew, when you review the log, it will show that it is failing to find the system include files at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/ffi`.

To correct this, run `xcode-select --install` to install the correct SDK version then you will be able to build Poppler via Homebrew.